# rounding off to the nearest number ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding

```
def percent_more
puts "What is the biggest number?"
biggest_number = gets.chomp
puts "What is the smallest number?"
smallest_number = gets.chomp
difference = biggest_number.to_i - smallest_number.to_i
total_percent_more = difference / smallest_number.to_f
puts "Your biggest number is #{total_percent_more}% bigger then your smallest number. Don't forget to round off to the nearest whole percent!"
```

end

Now that code will tell you what percent more biggest_number is than smallest_number. But the problem is it prints out a long list of decimals, which are a pain to sort through. So if I wanted the code to only show say the first 3 numbers what would I do??

Comment: Look at [Float#round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-round).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried that out by typing in 15 / 60.round(2) but it just came out with zero

Comment: Perhaps you meant `(15/60).round(2) => 0.0`, which is what you should get, because `15/60 => 0`, so that is `0.round(2) => 0.0`. Try this: `(15.0/60).round(2) => 0.25`, which is the same as `(15.to_f/60).round(2) => 0.25`. If either the numerator or denominator is a float, the computed ratio is a float. `15 / 60.round(2) => 15 / (60.round(2)) => 15 / 60.0 => 0.25`.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to use is `total_percent_more.round` like so:

```
puts "What is the biggest number?"
biggest_number = gets.chomp
puts "What is the smallest number?"                                                                        
smallest_number = gets.chomp                                                                               
difference = biggest_number.to_i - smallest_number.to_i                                                    
total_percent_more = difference / smallest_number.to_f                                                     
puts "Your biggest number is #{total_percent_more.round}% bigger then your smallest number. Don't forget to round off to the nearest whole percent!"
```

See the docs for more info :

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-round

in ruby versions earlier than 1.9 you'll need to use sprintf like so:

```
puts "Your biggest number is #{sprintf('%.2f', total_percent_more)}% bigger then your smallest number. Don't forget to round off to the nearest whole percent!"
```

You can change the amount of decimal places by changing the number.

See docs for more details:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Comment: I tried that with the numbers 5 and 45 but it still came out with 0. I was looking for the answer 0.11

Comment: You'd use `#{total_percent_more.round 2}` to get it to 2 decimal places.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using because I don't get that error

Comment: version 1.8.7 is what it says

Comment: Ah ... that function only rounds to the nearest int in 1.8.7. You'll need to use sprintf like so `sprintf('%.2f', total_percent_more)`. I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct, can you please accept the answer(The checkmark under this post, on the left)

Comment: Sorry it still doesnt work. But thanks for the help. I'll just scrap it

Answer (score 1):

```
result = 10/6.0
puts result
printf("%.3f\n", result)

--output:--
1.66666666666667
1.667
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to round to 2 decimal places

```
amount = 342
puts amount.round(2)
```

If you wanted to round to the nearest 3 decimal places then something like:

```
puts amount.round(3)
```